# SQL where clause for left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with a view I want to create. I have two tables joined in a left outer join, say `tableA` and `tableB`, where `tableB` is left outer joined.

I want to select only those rows from table B where state equals 4, so I add `WHERE state = 4` to my query. Now the result set is trimmed quite a bit because all rows without a matching row in `tableB` are removed from the result (since state isn't 4 for those rows). I also tried `WHERE state = 4 OR state IS NULL`, doesn't work either (since `state` technically isn't `NULL` when there is no state).

So what I need is a `WHERE` statement which is only evaluated when there actually is a row, does such a thing exist?

If not I see two options: `join (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE state = 4)` instead of table B, or create a view with the same `WHERE` statement and join that instead. What's the best option performance wise?

This is SQL Server 2008 R2 by the way.

Comment: It would be interesting to try to work out why `WHERE state = 4 OR state IS NULL` doesn't work, since it should prevent the left join being converted into an inner join.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - It would give you all rows from TableA not in TableB but not the rows where TableA has a match in TableB where state <> 4. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/110316/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: there are 3 states: matching with state = 4, matching with state <> 4, no match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You put the conditions in the `on` clause. Example:

```
select a.this, b.that
from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.id = a.id and b.State = 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `state = 4` to the join condition.

```
select * 
from T1
  left outer join T2
    on T1.T1ID = T2.T1ID and
       T2.state = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Even easier than a subquery is expanding the `on` clause, like;

```
select  *
from    TableA a
left    join
        TableB b
on      a.b_id = b.id
        and b.state = 4
```

All rows from TableA will appear, and only those from TableB with state 4.

SQL Server will probably execute the view, expanded `on`, and subquery in exactly the same way.  So performance wise, there should be little difference.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: (1) inner join to table B where state equals 4, (2) antijoin to table B to find rows that don't exist, (3) union the results:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.colA, B1.ColB
  FROM tableA AS A1
       INNER JOIN tableB AS B1
          ON A1.ID = B1.ID
             AND B1.state = 4
UNION
SELECT A1.ID, A1.colA, '{{MISSING}}' AS ColB
  FROM tableA AS A1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM tableB AS B1
                     WHERE A1.ID = B1.ID
                  );
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.colA, B1.ColB
  FROM tableA AS A1
       JOIN tableB AS B1
          ON A1.ID = B1.ID
             AND B1.state = 4
UNION
SELECT ID, colA, '{{NA}}' AS ColB
  FROM tableA 
 WHERE ID IN (
              SELECT ID
                FROM tableA
              EXCEPT 
              SELECT ID
                FROM tableB
             );
```